# jQuery Mobile - next page still has previous page meshed on top of new pages content

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-mobile

Right, I don't really know how to explain this one but I will do my best by giving a scenario:
Homepage -> Contact page
Home page elements and text displays on top of the contact pages text.

Anyone know why this would be happening? Or if there has been any issues like this from the past?

Help and suggestions will be much appreciated

Edit: There is also nested menus and it is always the homepage that displays on top of content. The url seems to change first to the secondary page url, then it suddenly changes to the homepage url. It also blinks but I think this is an issue that jQuery mobile havent fixed using jQuery mobile 1.2.0

Comment: Can you post an image and code. _A picture is worth 1000 words_.

Comment: Its ok I fixed it the problem seemed to lie in <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %> I had some other scripts in there i took them out and called them in a script tag instead (in the master)